# How to Manipulate DOM Elements in Typescript

Tags: typescript, dom

I have a problem regarding interacting with the DOM in Typescript. I have a DIV in an HTML file.  When I try to access it in Typescript I am getting the error illustrated below.

HTML Code

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="row"> </div>
</div>
```

Javascript Code

```js
const show = document.getElementById('row') as HTMLElement
console.log(show)
```

Console Errors

[image: error message]

Comment: It would probably be helpful to include the contents of the .ts file, or at least show the line of code where the error is being raised

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use `document.getElementById` or `document.querySelector` you are not guaranteed to find a matching element.  That's why the Typescript return type is `HTMLElement | null`.

When you use the type assertion `as HTMLElement` you are insisting that you will always have an `HTMLElement` and not `null`.  You aren't *checking* if you have an element, you are *asserting* that you do.

It turns out that your assertion was incorrect.  You actually had `null` and not an `HTMLElement`.  So you get a runtime error when trying to set `.innerHTML` on `null`.

As for *why* you can't find a matching element when one seems to exist in your app -- that I cannot answer from just what you've posted here.

But I can help with properly handling the possibility of `null` in your Typescript code.

```js
const show = document.getElementById('row');
if ( show ) {
  // inside of this if branch, show can only be `HTMLElement`
  show.innerHTML = "new inner HTML";
} else {
  console.error("no element found with id 'row'");
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="row"> </div>
</div>
```